# SQS DLQ log all messages without consuming them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The case I'm trying to face is - log the DLQ messages content, while avoiding ack the messages, in order to allow re-queue to original queue in the future.

I thought about subscribing two DLQs, when one is for logging, and second is for having the messages for re-queue, but its not possible

Answer (score 0):

You have to consume the SQS messages from DLQ as they have **limited retention period** (4 days by default). Thus, if you not act on them withing this period they will expire and you will loose them.

Normally, you would setup a **lambda function** which will process messages from the DLQ. Subsequently, you can do what you wish with these messages, which can include:

- re-broadcasting to the original queue
- sending SNS notifications about failed messages
- saving them into S3 or CloudWatch Logs for future analysis.

Comment: Any even driven pattern will not work in this case (Lambda for instance) since I like to consume the messages for logging and re-queue them

Comment: @gCoh If you don't remove them, they will get removed anyway, and you will loose them, by default after 4 days. You can re-submit them if you want to same or different queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a processing lambda(Event Source mapping) to get invoked when message falls into the DLQ and log the message contents in your cloudwatch log.

But ideally people will write the DLQ message into a file with the processing lambda and store them into s3 for logging/ auditing purposes